# How to add preference when numpy select meets two or more criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
           advblock    belthld    takuri    doji
stock A      100          0         0        0
stock B     -100          0         0        0
stock C       0          100       100       0
stock D     -100         100        0      -100
stock E       0           0        100      100
```

I want a new column that would store the name of pattern formed by each stock.
`100` = pattern formed, `-100` = inverse pattern formed. Note only some of the patterns can have `100` and `-100` both, like `advblock` and `doji`

Here is how I decided to do it:

```
cond = [
    (df['advblock'] == 100),
    (df['advblock'] == -100),
    (df['belthld'] == 100),
    (df['takuri'] == 100),
    (df['doji'] == 100),
    (df['doji'] == -100),
    ]
choices = ['Advance Block', 'Inv Advance Block','Belthold','Takuri','Doji','Inv Doji']
df['result'] = np.select(cond, choices)
```

This works fine until stock B where only one pattern qualifies per stock. However, in stock C, D, and E more than one pattern appears so I want the most accurate one to show up in results. Here is the accuracy list:

```
(+)advblock: 68%
(-)advblock: 71% 
belthold: 56%
takuri: 70%
(+)doji: 66%
(-)doji: 73%
```

I would want numpy select to consider that list when showing up results where the one with highest accuracy should be preferred over others.

I could have done something like this but it doesn't give me the liberty to change my column names and account for the inverse patterns:

```
d = {'advblock': .68, 'belthold': .56, 'takuri': .70, 'doji': .66}

df['result'] = df[sorted(d, key=lambda x: -d[x])].abs.eq(100).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Final intended result:

```
           advblock    belthld    takuri    doji         result
stock A      100          0         0        0        Advance Block
stock B     -100          0         0        0      Inv Advance Block
stock C       0          100       100       0           Takuri
stock D     -100         100        0      -100         Inv Doji
stock E       0           0        100      100          Takuri
```

Little help will be appreciated, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `melt` make the logic more obvious

```
s = df.reset_index().melt('index')
mappingdf=pd.DataFrame({'variable':['advblock','advblock','belthld','takuri','doji','doji'],
                         'value':[100,-100,100,100,100,-100],
                         'choice':['Advance Block', 'Inv Advance Block','Belthold','Takuri','Doji','Inv Doji'],
                         'acc' : [68,71,56,70,66,73]})
df['result'] = s.merge(mappingdf).sort_values('acc',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('index').set_index('index')['choice'].reindex(df.index).values
df
         takuri  advblock  doji  belthld             result
stock A       0       100     0        0      Advance Block
stock B       0      -100     0        0  Inv Advance Block
stock C     100         0     0      100             Takuri
stock D       0      -100  -100      100           Inv Doji
stock E     100         0   100        0             Takuri
```